# Выбор дат из указанного диапазона

Tags: mysql, sql, дата

Выводит лишние значения по такому запросу:

```
SELECT DISTINCT DATE_FORMAT(datetime, '%d.%m.%Y') AS `timedate` 
FROM `attendance` 
WHERE `personid`='1' 
  AND DATE_FORMAT(datetime, '%d.%m.%Y') >= '01.06.2015' 
  AND DATE_FORMAT(datetime, '%d.%m.%Y') <= '19.06.2015' 
ORDER BY datetime DESC
```

Не могу понять почему.
Результат запроса:

> 15.06.2015
>   11.06.2015
>   10.06.2015
>   09.06.2015
>   08.06.2015
>   01.06.2015
>   19.05.2015
>   11.05.2015

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может быть потому что надо указать

```
DATE_FORMAT(datetime, '%d.%m.%Y')>='01.06.2015'
```

вместо

```
DATE_FORMAT(datetime, '%d.%m.%Y')<='01.06.2015'
```

**UPD** Сейчас вы сравниваете не даты а строки отображающие даты, а если вам надо именно диапазон дат то либо:

```
DATE([Имя поля]) >= '2015-06-01' AND DATE([Имя поля]) <= '2015-06-19'
```

либо

```
DATE([Имя поля]) BETWEEN '2015-06-01' AND '2015-06-19'
```

Comment: @Regent - Вопрос: Выбор дат из указанного диапазона, а в запросе очевидная опечатка

Comment: Насчет _указанного диапазона_ справедливо.

Comment: да, я перепутал знак, когда вопрос писал. с правильным знаком выдает лишний результат

Answer (score 0):

Кусок "DATE_FORMAT(datetime, '%d.%m.%Y')<='01.06.2015' AND DATE_FORMAT(datetime, '%d.%m.%Y')<= '19.06.2015'" В этом куске 2 раза повторяется условие.
надо изменить на "DATE_FORMAT(datetime, '%d.%m.%Y')<= '19.06.2015'"

Comment: Заменить два условия на одно?

Comment: да, у тебя там стоит, что дата должна быть <= 1.06 и <= 19.06. т.е. условие с 1.06 лишнее

Comment: У меня там ничего не стоит. Проблема у автора в том, что строк в результате запроса больше нужного. Замена двух условий на одно сделает запрос короче и быстрее, но не решит проблему автора.

Comment: Помоему если идут такие "ложные" условия то он ставит знак задом наперед, т.е. вместо <= идет >=

Comment: да, я перепутал знак, когда вопрос писал. с правильным знаком выдает лишний результат